# Using getStorageAt() on mapping(address => uint64[])

Tags: web3js, contract-debugging

Given the contract variable `mapping(address => uint64[]) public foo`, can anyone help me access the data using web3?

Assuming we have the account address (`0xF89...`) and that `foo` is in slot 5, I can access the length of the array using:

```
key   = '00000000000000000000000xF895a7D153d80A52aE9C32C30400e000censored'
index = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005'
let varAddress = web3.sha3(key + index, {"encoding":"hex"})   // k . p
let res = web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, varAddress);
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to access the data in the array itself.

I've been trying to decipher the relevant section in [Layout of State Variables in Storage](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage), and [this article](https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925) was also helpful, but can't quite get it. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

My blog post on the subject has a very similar example: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/.

Assuming `varAddress` is correct (doesn't necessarily look correct from your code, but I imagine that's not an exact copy/paste), you need to hash that location and then add the index. Something like this (untested):

```
var location = web3.toBigNumber(web3.sha3(varAddress), { encoding: 'hex' })
    .add(n).toString(16);
```

where `n` is the index into the array you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since the mapping is public, Solidity automatically creates a getter for it, you can use it.

```
let varAddress = web3.sha3(key + index, {"encoding":"hex"})   // k . p
let res = contract.foo(varAddress);
```

You will need to initialise the `contract` variable with the `web3.eth.Contract` function.